# Resizing Ubuntu Partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, gparted

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 11, initially giving Ubuntu 33GB.
Now I want to install larger programs, thus my 33 GB are not enough. I went on Windows and I removed 80 GBs from the Windows partition, now I am on Ubuntu and I have no clue on how to give these 80GBs to the Ubuntu partition to increase the storage space inside of the OS to install larger programs. The blue square (`/dev/nvme0n1p5`) is the Ubuntu partition.

How can I allocate the extra space I made to Ubuntu?

[image: Screenshot of GParted]

[image: second screenshot]

[image: Last screenshot]

Comment: **Make sure you have a backup before messing with partitions any more**. It isn't too difficult, but you should have a backup in case you mess up

Comment: An alternative is to create a new partition and use it as /home for your data. Then giving more room in / (root). To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  You can change to / and then use `sudo ncdu` to see sizes of your folders. You may have to install ncdu as only du is standard. `sudo apt-install ncdu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/nvme0n1p4 partition all the way left
- **move** /dev/nvme0n1p5 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/nvme0n1p5 all the way right
- click the Apply icon
- reboot to Ubuntu and confirm free space
- boot to Windows to confirm that it still boots

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134097/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-resizing-ubuntu-partition).